# alias - cd followed by ls

Tags: linux, alias, cd

How can I define an alias so that when I do `cd Abcd`, where 'Abcd' is the name of a directory, the directory is changed to 'Abcd' and is followed by `ls` to show the contents of the directory?

Comment: This [link](http://superuser.com/a/238858) should help you:           http://superuser.com/a/238858

Comment: What OS and command line interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can't use an alias to accomplish that, but you could define a function to do it:

```
#print contents after moving to given directory
cl()
{
    cd $@
    ls
}
```

You could stick this in your `~/.bashrc` file.

If you were hoping to override the builtin `cd` command, then you could do:

```
#print contents after moving to given directory
cd()
{
    builtin cd $@
    ls
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Though, I prefer leaving my .bashrc file alone for the most part and placing these inside .bash_aliases or some other external file where manual additions are kept (.zsh_aliases for me).

Answer (score -1):

## UNIX

#### Creating an alias

Your Linux distribution will most likely not have the .bash_aliases file created in your home, or you can even create it manually. To create the file, type in the following command:
`touch ~/.bash_alisaes`

Now that file will be executed automatically every time you fire off a new Terminal.

What you can do now is create a list of aliases and add them to that file for later uses.
create an alias and update the ~/.bash_aliases file to make it permanent.

#### Generic approach: Creating a custom script

Create a bash script in your /usr/bin folder, it should look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
Whatever combination of commands you want to run when you type this thing.
```

Its really that easy.

Just name the bash script what you want to type in to the terminal, and make it excecutable: chmod +x filename and you're good to go!

## WINDOWS

You can use **DOSKEY** command:

From Wikipedia:

> DOSKey is a utility for MS-DOS and Microsoft Windows that adds command
> history, macro functionality, and improved editing features to the
> command line interpretersCOMMAND.COM and cmd.exe. It was included as a
> TSR program with MS-DOS and PC-DOS versions 5 and later, and with
> Microsoft's Windows 95/98/Me.

For example: To create a macro that quickly and unconditionally formats a disk, type:

> doskey qf=format $1 /q /u

To quickly and unconditionally format a disk in drive Z, type:

> qf Z:

To define a macro with multiple commands, use $t to separate commands, so the solution to your problem follows:

> doskey cd=cd $1$tdir

Now, this will work only in your currently open command window. To make it permanent simply create a batch file and set the value of the absolute path of the file to the *regedit*

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

Source for the regedit: [superuser.com/a/238858](https://superuser.com/a/238858)

Comment: Question is tagged linux - so this seems like the wrong answer.

Comment: @GodEater The question wasn't tagged `linux` when it was answered. I can delete the answer if you want.