# How to create alias in Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, zsh, alias, ls, cd

Every time I type `cd folder` or `cd ..` I would like it to immediately run `ls` after.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I suggest to use a function.

Comment: See: [alias - cd followed by ls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14146530/3776858)

Comment: @airbornesnow: The question, as you wrote it, does not make sense. An alias is not bound to a _terminal_, but to the _shell_. Further, you are not clear in which shell you are using, as you are tagging the question as _zsh_ and as _bash_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reposting the answer from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146530/alias-cd-followed-by-ls)**

Put this in .zshrc to create alias for cl:

```
#print contents after moving to given directory
cl()
{
    cd $@
    ls
}
```

To override cd (not recommended), put this in .zshrc:

```
#print contents after moving to given directory
cd()
{
    builtin cd $@
    ls
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend against overriding `cd` itself but essentially what you would like to do is:

```sh
alias cdl='cd $*; ls'
```

Here `cdl` is the name of your new command (it could also be `cd` if you really insist) and then you are assigning it to another command, which is itself a sequence of two commands:

- `cd $*` where `$*` refers to all the arguments you are passing to `cdl`
- `ls`
  You could condition the execution of `ls` on the success of `cd` i.e. only run it if `cd` is given a valid folder and just do nothing otherwise:

```sh
alias cdl='cd $* && ls'
```

**UPDATE**

@Cyrus, you are right, this doesn't work from within an alias (though it does if you just run from from the command line directly). This works though:

```sh
alias cdl='ls $*; cd $*'
```

Comment: This does not do the intended thing. It switches to `~` and then lists `$*`.

Comment: I take it back. This doesn't seem to work actually. It always switches to my home directory for some reason.

Comment: See: [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/3776858)

Comment: the new version works, @Cyrus - so it seems aliases can take parameters after all

Comment: This lists current directory and then cd to $*.